# Is it possible to hide custom attribute from product editor and assign a default value?

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, custom-attributes

**Goal**

1. Create a custom boolean attribute called "is_type" & default the value to "1"
2. Assign custom attribute to a single attribute set
3. Products assigned to this attribute set automatically have "is_type" set to 1 when the product is saved

**Code**

```
    $eavSetup->addAttribute(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
        'is_type',
        [
            'group' => 'General',
            'type' => 'int',
            'backend' => '',
            'frontend' => '',
            'label' => 'Is Type',
            'input' => 'boolean',
            'class' => '',
            'source' => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Boolean',
            'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
            'visible' => 0,
            'required' => 1,
            'user_defined' => 0,
            'default' => '1',
            'searchable' => 1,
            'filterable' => 0,
            'comparable' => 0,
            'visible_on_front' => 0,
            'used_in_product_listing' => 1,
            'is_used_in_grid' => 1,
            'unique' => false,
            'apply_to' => 'simple',
            'attribute_set' => 'CustomAttributeSet'
        ]
    );
```

I can see that the attribute is created, however, creating a new product and assigning the new product to "CustomAttributeSet" does not appear to assign the attribute to the product.

**Edit:**

Testing the product using the steps below, I see that the value is actually correct and assigned.

- `magerun dev:console`

  - `$di->get('Magento\Framework\App\State')->setAreaCode('frontend')`
  - `$di->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load(2051)->getData('is_type')`

I was expecting `magento index:reindex && magento cache:clean` to update the Visual Merchandiser products for the category that I associated with this attributed. However, for whatever reason, I had to save the category in order to refresh Visual Merchandiser Products.

Answer (score 0):

Testing the product using the steps below, I see that the value is actually correct and assigned.

- `magerun dev:console`

  - `$di->get('Magento\Framework\App\State')->setAreaCode('frontend')`
  - `$di->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load(2051)->getData('is_type')`

I was expecting `magento index:reindex && magento cache:clean` to update the Visual Merchandiser products for the category that I associated with this attributed. However, for whatever reason, I had to save the category in order to refresh Visual Merchandiser Products.